# Circular dependency with the relationships "contains" and "is in"

Tags: c++, architecture, software-design

I would like to gather opinion from you about the following problem.

We have a class called "Room". Each room may contain zero or more instances of a class "Person", so the Room stores a collection of Persons (e.g. vector). It **owns** them. However, there is some time-consuming logic related to moving Persons between Rooms, so the Person also contains current Room they are in. It is just a **pointer without ownership**. This information is theoretically redundant, because one could derive it from the collections of Persons in rooms, but assuming large number of rooms >> number of people, such an operation would be slow...

```
class Room {
std::vector<Person> peopleInside;
};

class Person {
Room* currentRoom; //could be shared_ptr to avoid raw pointers
};
```

Naturally, it is more complex (classes have more than this) but I have simplified it as much as possible.

My questions are:

1) In this situation, is this a circular dependency per se?

2) Is this solution dirty/inelegant for you?

3) Is it worth changing to something else?

Comment: If the persons shall move around between the rooms a lot, I think a vector<Person> could be a bad choice.

Comment: What I don't like is that this design can give inconsistent states, i.e. a Person in Room A may point to Room B. But to evaluate whether that can be avoided, it will be necessary with some use case description, i.e. what kind of operations is to be carried out on the data? For instance I imagine that one operation is to move Person X to Room A, right? So how do you get hold of the person? A name to search for? How do you get hold of Room A. Do you have a vector of Room?

Comment: Yeah, I agree on both - storing direct objects can result in too much copying and inconsistent states are possible.

I have a graph of rooms and transitions between them. A person may move to an adjacent room if there is a transition, a move is an action (as in a game) and the game logic will update the collections so they are synchronized... but I myself see weak points of this design...

Comment: Can you describe why Person needs to know about the Room? From the description in your comment is sounds as if your controller already know which rooms are involved.

Comment: @4386427 It might be convenient.  Otherwise, if you only have a `Person` on hand, you would have to ask your container of `Rooms` (whatever that is) to find which `Room` that person is currently in and that would involve some kind of search.

Comment: @PaulSanders It might .... But since the use cases ain't clear, it's not possible to come up with a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question needs really to be studied in context.  If `Person`s only exist in the context of a `Room` then the back-pointer is safe.  When a `Room` is destroyed then the `Person`s are destroyed too (boom!) so nothing can go wrong.

But I suspect that's too simplistic.  The declaration of `Room` is more likely to be something like:

```
class Room {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Person>> peopleInside;
};
```

And now we have a possible 'dangling pointer' problem, which you can't solve with a `std::shared_pointer<Room>` in `Person` because then you *do* have a circular dependency and neither `shared_ptr` will ever be able to delete the object it is managing (because `Room` holds a reference to `Person` and vice versa, so, deadlock).

So instead, declare `Person` like this:

```
class Person {
    std::weak_ptr<Room> currentRoom;
};
```

And initialise `currentRoom` from some `shared_ptr<Room>` that you keep available while that `Room` exist.  This breaks the circular dependency.

To dereference `currentRoom`, you can then do:

```
if (auto room_I_am_currently_in = currentRoom.lock())
{
    room_I_am_currently_in->OpenDoor ();
}
```

And if the original `shared_ptr<Room>` has been destroed then `lock` will fail.  The lock will be released when `room_I_am_currently_in` goes out of scope (it's actually a `shared_ptr<Room>`).

And to move a person to another room, just reassign `currentRoom`.

More about `std::weak_ptr` at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).